# update users table through object id without login in parse.com(USING REST API)

Tags: php, json, curl, parse-platform

I want to update User table of DATA BROWSER using objectId(With out getting user to log in ) using following code.

But I am getting:

```
error({"code":101,"error":"object not found for update"})
```

can any one tell me what is wrong with this:

```
$className = "Classname";

$objectIdToEdit = $_SESSION['objectId'];

$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/' . $className . '/' . $objectIdToEdit;

$appId = '***********************';
$restKey = '***********';
$updatedData = '{"firstname":"Billie123"}';

$rest = curl_init();
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_PORT,443);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"PUT");
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$updatedData);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appId,
    "X-Parse-Master-Key: " . $restKey,
    "Content-Type: application/json")
);

$response = curl_exec($rest);
echo $response;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem my self ,URL I was using is to save data

```
 $url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/' . $className . '/' . $objectIdToEdit;
```

I just changed URL to update data and problem is solved

```
$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/' . $className . '/' . $objectIdToEdit;
```

thanks Ghost for editing